# How to assign column values from one dataframe to another in a robust fashion i.e., no crash on missing?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following use case:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [4,5,6], 'c': [7, 8, 9]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=np.nan, columns=['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd'])

# now i'd like to populate df2 in one go
df2 = df1[df2.columns.tolist()]
```

but filling up df2 fails because not all the columns exist, I would like it to be populated and when the column doesn't exist in df1 simply fill it with NAs. So basically a `ignore_errors` version of the [] operator.

Note that I could loop over the columns but it is very inelegant / inefficient.

Comment: `df1.reindex(df2.columns, axis=1)`

Comment: Indeed that's the answer! thanks a lot!